# Switch Webpack Entry point on switching to new Route

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, babeljs

I have a running React Application containing two routes

1. "/app"
2. "/dashboard"

Also I have two entry points in webpack

```
entry: {
  a: 'browser.app.jsx',
  b: 'browser.dashboard.jsx'
}
```

I need to synchronize the routes with entry points. Like

Entry Point should be (a) again Route (1)

Entry point should be (b) against Route (2)

How can I achieve this functionality ?

Comment: Are you familiar with [code splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/)?

Comment: Not really. Can u please elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two entry points to do what you want.
As @or-b commented, code splitting is the way to go. Webpack will do this for you. You just have to import the files you want to lazy load with `import().then()`.
Here is an example for react router

```
export default {
    component: App,
    childRoutes: [
        {
            path: '/dashboard',
            getComponent(location, cb) {
                import('browser.dashboard.jsx').then(({ default: module }) => cb(null, module));
            }
        },
    ]
};
```

This should already do what you want. You can define how the chunks will be called in output in you webpack config.

```
output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js',
},
```

Comment: Actually I am working on enterprise level application and there my main purpose is to maintain the bundle size. If i create parent, child routes then it will cause the increment of bundle size. So that's why i am trying to create multiple entry points.

Comment: It won't increase the bundle size. Your entry point would just be your core react project and every route will have its own chunk which gets loaded on demand. The only disadvantage is that you need to load two files instead of one on pageload, but they will be a lot smaller.